# Error: mixpanel-react-native: MixpanelReactNative is null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Error: mixpanel-react-native: MixpanelReactNative is null.

at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0

I've followed the guide on the Github repository: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-react-native fix this bug but its still persisting

Comment: Hard to help without seeing any code or configuration, can you add the relevant information?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.